# Excerpts on category page

Tags: plugins, posts, excerpt

Is there an easy way to get a specific category page to display excerpts with x amount of words then have a read more link to link to the full post? I've tried the advanced excerpts plugin which does what I want but i want to be able to restrict it to certain categories

Answer (score 0):

Try this and place in your functions.php file:

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 35;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function excerpt_more( $more ) {
return sprintf( '%2$s',
get_permalink( get_the_ID() ),
__( 'Read More', 'textdomain' )
);
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'excerpt_more' );